# How to open steam overlay to purchase item via steam_api.h

Tags: steam, steamworks-api

How can I open steam overlay to purchase X amount of items? I have only amount and itemdef. Steam documentation says I have to make http request and setup total price I want to charge, but that's weird because I already specified item price in itemdef.